# Passing an array and its length with a struct in C weird behavior

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, struct

I'm trying to return an array and its length from one function to another. I've learned that I can't simply determine the size of the returning array in the parent function with sizeof() because arrays are reduced to pointers when passed as parameters. I've figured out that I can [use a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493281/c-sizeof-a-passed-array) to return the array pointer and size to the parent function, so that's what I'm attempting.

The array is of type unsigned char* since I'm working with memory addresses. The array appears fine before it is sent to the struct. Once I try to reference the array via the struct in a parent function, all of the memory addresses are split up. I have a hunch that struct padding could be the problem.

I've written some prints to really analyze what's going on.

```
struct arrayPasser{
    int length;
    unsigned char *arr;
};

unsigned char *arr[arrLength]; /*array of pointers*/

/*filling out the array with addresses*/

struct arrayPasser pass;

pass.length=arrLength;
pass.arr=&arr;

printf("pass.arr: %#x\n", pass.arr); /*print array location*/

printf("*(&arr): %#x\n", *(&arr));
printf("**(&arr): %#x\n", **(&arr));

/*original array*/
printf("arr[0] %#x\n", arr[0]);     
printf("arr[1] %#x\n", arr[1]);
printf("arr[2] %#x\n", arr[2];

/*referencing array through struct*/
printf("0 offset: %#x\n", *pass.arr);
printf("1 offset: %#x\n", *(pass.arr+1));
printf("2 offset: %#x\n", *(pass.arr+2));
printf("3 offset: %#x\n", *(pass.arr+3);
printf("4 offset: %#x\n", *(pass.arr+4));
printf("5 offset: %#x\n", *(pass.arr+5));
printf("6 offset: %#x\n", *(pass.arr+6));
printf("7 offset: %#x\n", *(pass.arr+7));

printf("pass.arr[0]: %#x\n", pass.arr[0]);
printf("pass.arr[1]: %#x\n", pass.arr[1]);
printf("pass.arr[2]: %#x\n", pass.arr[2]);
printf("pass.arr[3]: %#x\n", pass.arr[3]);
printf("pass.arr[4]: %#x\n", pass.arr[4]);
printf("pass.arr[5]: %#x\n", pass.arr[5]);
printf("pass.arr[6]: %#x\n", pass.arr[6]);
printf("pass.arr[7]: %#x\n", pass.arr[7]);
```

Output (notice how arr[0] is a full 32-bit address but pass.arr[0] is only one byte of the 32-bit address) :

```
arr[0] 0x4affb000
arr[1] 0x4affd000
arr[2] 0x4affc000
pass.arr: 0x58dcf10
*(&arr): 0x58dcf10
**(&arr): 0x4affb000
0 offset: 0
1 offset: 0xb0
2 offset: 0xff
3 offset: 0x4a
4 offset: 0
5 offset: 0xd0
6 offset: 0xff
7 offset: 0x4a
pass.arr[0]: 0
pass.arr[1]: 0xb0
pass.arr[2]: 0xff
pass.arr[3]: 0x4a
pass.arr[4]: 0
pass.arr[5]: 0xd0
pass.arr[6]: 0xff
pass.arr[7]: 0x4a
```

Comment: `&arr` is not an `unsigned char *`.

Comment: I just typecasted it to an `unsigned char *` before sending it to a struct and it retained it's correct value so I'm not sure that is the root of the problem, but good to know.

Comment: The cast is pointless. Just use `arr`.

Comment: You don't represent an array of pointers with `unsigned char *arr;`.  That's representing an array of char (or a simple char pointer).

Comment: I'm using `unsigned char *` because I'm working with raw memory on an embedded system and I thought I'd go with advice from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769917/when-to-use-unsigned-char-pointer).

Comment: Sometimes `char*` is used instead of `void*` to represent an undifferentiated storage location.  But you can't effectively dereference that any more than you can dereference `void*`.  It must be cast to an appropriate type first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unsigned char *arr[arrLength]` is an array of pointers, but since arrays are essentially pointers, the variable `arr` points to the first pointer in the array, so it is an equivalent to `unsigned char **arr`.

But `unsigned char *arr` is a pointer to `char`, but not a pointer to a pointer. In other words, it is array of `char`, but not array of pointers.

Declare your structure as:

```
struct arrayPasser{
    int length;
    unsigned char **arr;
};
```

And you will get a pointer instead of char when you dereference the `arr`.

Let me try to explain why your code doesn't work. Consider this array:

```
unsigned char *arr[3]
arr[0] = 0x4affb000;
arr[1] = 0x4affd000;
arr[2] = 0x4affc000;
```

When you do that, the data you entered placed in the memory like this:

```
00 b0 ff 4a   00 d0 ff 4a   00 c0 ff 4a
^             ^             ^
|             |             |
arr           arr + 1       arr + 2
points here   points here   points here
```

The integers stored in the memory have little endian byte order, so their bytes are reversed.

When you do `arr[0]` you get `0x4affb000` because sizeof(arr[0]) is 4, hence you get 4 bytes.

Then, you do this:

```
unsigned char *arr2 = arr;  /* which is equal to arr2 = &arr */
```

The memory isn't changed, but the way the pointer behaves is changed. Now it is a pointer to `char`, not a pointer to pointer, so the size of an object referenced by the pointer is now 1 instead of 4. In other words, both `arr` and `arr2` point to the same memory location, but  size of an element of `arr` is 4 and size of an element of `arr2` is 1.

Here is what you get for `arr2`:

```
00 b0 ff 4a   00 d0 ff 4a   00 c0 ff 4a
^  ^  ^  ^
|  |  |  +--arr2 + 3
|  |  +--arr2 + 2
|  +--arr2 + 1
+--arr2
```

Now when you do `arr2[0]` you get `0x00` because sizeof(arr2[0]) is 1 byte.

Comment: That hurts my head to think about, but I guess it makes sense and it fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Pointers and arrays are **entirely** different. When the name of an array is used in an expression, it is (with some exceptions) converted to a pointer, but that does **not** make it a pointer.

Comment: Indeed, I got excited when I said that arrays are almost pointers, sorry for that. I had to say that they are equivalent in a certain subset of operations (accessing an element and dereferencing a pointer).

Comment: Arrays are not essentially pointers. It is confusing to try and think of arrays as being essentially pointers. In fact that is the root of OP's confusion in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

(Apparently, the output is from a different program than the one you posted, but never mind.)

```
pass.length=arrLength;
pass.arr=&arr;
```

You are trying to convert a **pointer to array** to a **pointer to unsigned char**. The two types are not compatible, so you're going to need to cast `&arr` to the right type. But that's not what you want. See below.

```
printf("pass.arr: %#x\n", pass.arr); /*print array location*/
```

Note: The `%x` conversion specifier expects a parameter of type `unsigned int`. You should cast `pass.arr` to `unsigned int` or cast it to `(void *)` and print it using the `%p` specifier.

```
printf("*(&arr): %#x\n", *(&arr));
```

Passing `arr` to `printf()`. This is a pointer to the first element of the `arr` array.

```
printf("**(&arr): %#x\n", **(&arr));
```

Passing `*arr` to `printf()`. This is the first pointer stored in the `arr` array, eg. `arr[0]`.

```
printf("arr[0] %#x\n", arr[0]);     
printf("arr[1] %#x\n", arr[1]);
printf("arr[2] %#x\n", arr[2]); /* Added missing ')'. */
```

Passing the first three pointers stored in `arr` to `printf()`.

```
printf("0 offset: %#x\n", *pass.arr);
printf("1 offset: %#x\n", *(pass.arr+1));
printf("2 offset: %#x\n", *(pass.arr+2));
printf("3 offset: %#x\n", *(pass.arr+3);
```

Passing the first four elements pointed to by `pass.arr` to `printf()`. The elements pointed to by `pass.arr` are of type **`unsigned char`**, not `unsigned char *`. Since the `unsigned char` is passed to a variadic function, it will be promoted to `int` (or in obscure cases `unsigned int`) which will in all probability be printed just fine.

The reason the addresses appear to be split up is that the contents of `arr` (pointers) are now being reinterpreted as an array of characters through `pass.arr`.

```
printf("pass.arr[0]: %#x\n", pass.arr[0]);
printf("pass.arr[1]: %#x\n", pass.arr[1]);
printf("pass.arr[2]: %#x\n", pass.arr[2]);
printf("pass.arr[3]: %#x\n", pass.arr[3]);
```

Exactly the same as above. The `A[B]` notation is (mostly) equivalent to `*((A)+(B))`.

If you want to return a pointer to `arr` through your `struct arrayPasser`, you need to pass a **pointer** to pointer, not just a pointer. Change your struct to:

```
struct arrayPasser{
    int length;
    unsigned char **arr;
};
```

And assign a pointer to the first element of `arr` to it:

```
pass.arr = arr;
```

As I explained above, you can't assign `&arr` to `pass.arr`, even if the pointer **value** happens to be exactly the same. The two pointers have entirely different **types**.

Apparently you didn't think this subject was confusing enough, so you went right ahead and gave two different identifiers the same name. :-)