# C++ Syntax of casting operators on struct object

Tags: c++11

What does the syntax of the following cast to an object `Page` of struct  `WHISPERPACKET` mean

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char uchData[512];
    unsigned char uchType;
    unsigned char uchInfo;
    unsigned short unSampleRate;
    unsigned short unSamples;
}WHISPERPACKET;
```

```
typedef unsigned char       BYTE;
WHISPERPACKET Page;


PageBuffer = (BYTE*)&Page;
```

edit:

```
BYTE* PageBuffer;
```

Comment: The declaration of `PageBuffer` is missing, hopefully it's of type `BYTE *`, to which the address of `Page` is casted. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769917/when-to-use-unsigned-char-pointer

Comment: The cast is not applied to the object `Page`, but to a `Page*` pointer `&Page`. The goal is likely to access the underlying storage of `Page` as an array of bytes.