# Pointers in a function C language

Tags: c, pointers

Hello i am new to C language and trying to understand pointers.

Doing some examples i stumbled with this function and im not completely sure what it is about.

```c
void dump(void *p, int n)
{
    unsigned char *p1 = p;
    while (n--)
    {
        printf("%p - %02x\n", p1, *p1);
        p1++;
    }
}
```

I dont understand the `p` in `unsigned char *p1 = p;` there is no other use for it in the function. I also dont quite understand the `p1` in `printf("%p - %02x\n", p1, *p1);`, is it the actual value of the *p1 pointer?

Can anyone explain this topics to me? I'll be very grateful.

In the example it shows me that when a i run with this main()

```c
int main(void)
{
    int i = 10000;
    dump(&i, sizeof(i));
    return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
0x7ffd7e787e74 - 10
0x7ffd7e787e75 - 27
0x7ffd7e787e76 - 00
0x7ffd7e787e77 - 00
```

Comment: It's treating a `pointer-to-void` as a `pointer-to-unsigned char` so that it can iterate through the memory it's pointed to byte-by-byte, and the loop does this and prints the address and outputs the value at that byte as hex. Look at other threads like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769917/when-to-use-unsigned-char-pointer

Answer (score 2):

> `unsigned char *p1 = p;` there is no other use for it in the function.

But there is. `void` has no size and arithmetics on a `void*` wouldn't know how far a "step" when trying to step the pointer to the next element of the pointed out type, as `p1++;` means. Where should it point after adding `1`?

`char`, that is the smallest addressable entity, on the other hand, has a well defined size (`1`), and `p1++` means the same as stepping one `char` (byte) in memory, resulting in pointing at the next `char` (byte).

---

`void` is special. You can't instantiate/store `void`. `void` is what you use to define a procedure/function that has no return value, `void func(...);`. It's also what's used to define a function that doesn't accept any arguments, `... func(void);`.

A `void*` can be used to point at any type of object, of any size, from a `char`, with size `1`, to a `megaobject`, of size *gigantic*. `void*` is therefore often used to accept pointers to any type of object - but, actually stepping a pointer `1` step ahead means "step to the next object of the pointed out type in memory" which also means that the compiler needs to know the size of the object the pointer is pointing at. Converting the `void*` to a `(unsigned) char*` and using that pointer lets the function step (`p1++`) forward in memory, one byte at a time.

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned char *p1 = p;` converts the value of `p` from `void *` to `unsigned char *` and stores it in `p1`. This conversion yields the same address but with information that it points to a different type.

`printf("%p - %02x\n", p1, *p1);` should properly be `printf("%p - %02hhx\n", (void *) p1, *p1);`. In this, `%p` formats the address passed to it (the value of `p1`) for display, so it shows a memory address in a human-readable way. Since the type of `p1` is `unsigned char *`, `*p1` is an `unsigned char` at the address `p1` points to, and `%02hhx` converts its value to a hexadecimal numeral with at least `2` digits, using a leading `0` digit if necessary.